# Getting error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the type error not sure why I am seeing this error.

```
print(str(genNum)) + ': ' + os.path.basename(fileItem) + ' =>\n' + os.path.basename(newname) + "\n"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

```
for fileItem in glob.glob(path):
    if i < condition_number:
    condition_name = renameConfig['condition_order'][i]
    real_name = renameConfig['condition'][condition_name]['postfix']
    
    number_of_image = renameConfig['condition'][condition_name]['number_of_image']
    
    if number_of_image > 1:
        newname = prefixed_name + real_name + '_' + str(j) + fileType
    else:
        newname = prefixed_name + real_name + fileType
    
    os.rename(fileItem, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(fileItem), newname))
    print(str(genNum)) + ': ' + os.path.basename(fileItem) + ' =>\n' +os.path.basename(newname) + "\n"
    fileNameDict[fileItem] = newname
```

Comment: `print(str(genNum))` returns `None`. And you are trying to add `': '` to it. Did you mean to add `str(genNum)` to `': '` inside the `print` function?

Comment: `print(str(genNum))` returns `None`

Comment: In your print line you have 2 parentheses after genNum. Remove one of them and add it to the end of the line. I think that'll give you what you were after